# How to use vectrs or keys in seaborn.relplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I can plot with multiple x and y using plot.scatter.
But I can not plot that with Seaborn.relplot even though documentation notice "x, y vector's' or key's' in data"

```
df.plot.scatter(x=['U','S','L'], y=['UI','SI','LI'])  # this works
sns.relplot(x=['U','S','L'], y=['UI','SI','LI'],data=df)  # this doesn't work
```

the error msg says "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index".

how can i do plot multiple x and y figure using Seaborn.relplot?
thank you for your reply
it will be great help

```
   R  W    L        LI    S        SI    U        UI
0  AZ  1  300  3.173333  219  4.538813  129  7.263566
1  AZ  2  293  3.266212  224  4.446429  155  5.954839
2  AD  3  279  3.240143  212  4.481132  152  5.993421
3  AD  4  277  3.494585  199  4.567839  110  8.272727
4  AW  5  257  3.863813  211  4.725118  152  6.315789
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not passible to pass multiple values to the `sns.relplot`.

But as a workaround you can join multiple scatterplot using `sns.scatterplot`.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'R':['AZ', 'AZ', 'AD', 'AD', 'AW'],
                   'W':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'L':[300,293,279,277,257],
                   'LI':[3.173333, 3.266212, 3.240143, 3.494585, 3.863813],
                   'S':[219,224,212, 199, 211],
                   'SI':[4.538813,4.446429, 4.481132, 4.567839, 4.725118],
                   'U':[129, 155, 152, 110, 152],
                   'UI':[7.263566, 5.954839, 5.993421, 8.272727, 6.315789]
                  })

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, height=5)
for x, y, c in zip(['U','S','L'],['UI','SI','LI'], ['r', 'g', 'b']):
    g.map(sns.scatterplot, x, y, color=c)
g.set_axis_labels('[U, S, L]', '[UI, SI, LI]')
```

**Output**

[image: multiple seaborn scatter plots in one figure]

**Comment**

I don't know if this is what you are asking for. Please give me some feedback.